# applescript to save email-attachments in a folder doesn't work in Yosemite

Tags: operating-system, applescript, email-attachments, osx-yosemite

I've installed OS x 10.10.1
Now this script doesn't work:

```
tell application "Mail"
  set theSelectedMessages to selection
  set  this_message to item 1 of the theSelectedMessages
        tell this_message
           set these_attachments to every mail attachment
                repeat with z from 1 to the count of these_attachments
                set this_attachment to item z of these_attachments
                set this_name to the name of this_attachment as text
```

.........and so on

I get the message : error in the apple event Routine. The error comes in this line: "set these_attachments to every mail attachment"

In 10.9 the script worked.

WoWo
woide@wwp-service.de

Comment: works for me using gmail imap on Yosemite

Answer (score 0):

G'day from the land of Oz

Your code, slightly modified, works. I think your use of 'selection' might be faulty, but haven't test it. Try 'selected mailbox'.

Regards

Brian Christmas

```html
tell application "Mail"
 set theSelectedMessages to messages of mailbox "* items to shift"
 set this_message to item 1 of the theSelectedMessages
 tell this_message
  set these_attachments to every mail attachment
  set AttachmentNames to {}
  repeat with z from 1 to the count of these_attachments
   set this_attachment to item z of these_attachments
   set this_name to the name of this_attachment as rich text
   set end of AttachmentNames to this_name as rich text
  end repeat
 end tell
end tell
AttachmentNames & return & z

--> {"2014-11-10 233839Z.zip", "2014-11-10 233839Z.zip", "(20141110233839Z 2).pdf", "2014-11-10 233839Z", "
", 4}
```

Comment: Welcome to so.. You may omit ...'Regards' etc